# while doing json parsing i'm getting exception as ::-->> reason: : unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topaudiobooks/limit=10/json"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;

NSData *downloadData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:url returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if (!error) {
       NSDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:downloadData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
       NSLog(@"%@",dict);
}
```

Comment: First: Show the whole error message. It should give you what's the method causing issue and on what kind of object it's called. Also, your code should give you a warning because `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` awaits for a `NS(Mutable)Request` request object for its first parameter => replace `url` with `request`. Other side notes: Avoid calling synchronous request, in called in mainthread, they block UI, and it's deprecated also since iOS9, use `NSURLSession` instead.

Answer (score -2):

The method you are using is expecting an `NSMutableURLRequest` object, while you are passing an `NSURL`. - trying replacing "url" with "request" in your code and you are good to go.